# Satellite data in Russia?

Tags: satellite

Anyone familiar with options for transmitting data in Russia?  I'd be interested in hearing about low-speed packet data and faster.  Not really looking at VSAT initially as I'd like to keep the power requirements low unless we find no other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you need to contact the local providers, like Golden Telecom or masterhost.ru

I'm no expert on the market there, but afaik, it also highly depends on the area you're looking to communicate with, since service providers vary, and Russia is VERY large.

Comment: Thanks for the names - this will be in remote locations so satellite seems like the logical choice for us.  We have been using L-Band here in North America but I'm finding it hard to find a similar service in Russia.  Closest seems to be a 384 kbit terminal via Thuraya but I'm unsure of their coverage in Russia.

Answer (score 0):

Im dot sure about commercial usability, but look http://www.gonets.ru/english.php